# Where is the Treasure located in The Mountain Path area of the Ignan Ruins (2-1)?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

I've purchased the hint from the Priest to try to figure out how to find the treasure, which is in the spoiler below:

> Nature provides the drums, you provide the beat

I... have no idea what this means. The only thing I can think of is that it possibly has something to do with the mushrooms? Because... mushrooms sort of... look like drums?

What I have tried:

- Killing all the mushrooms first
- Killing everything but the mushrooms and leaving them for last (this is actually harder than it sounds)
- Hitting the 3 rocks in the zone both clockwise and counter-clockwise (both with and without enemies in the zone)
- Killing everything
- Killing the wasp nests first
- Killing the wasp nests last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you almost got Nature's Drums right. There are **five** rocks you need to strike in order to get the chest to spawn. You don't need to hit them in any sequence, you need simply make sure you strike them hard enough for that nice CLANG sound. The screenshots will include the minimap so you know exactly where they are. It isn't all that hard to see them, but it's easy to miss which ones you've actually hit.

The first 3 rocks are all on the main area. One right at the entrance...

[image: First Rock location]

One to the west...

[image: Western Rock location]

One to the east...

[image: Eastern Rock location]

The other two are on the raised areas. The fourth one you should hit is the platform near the entrance.

[image: High Rock location]

The final rock you should do is the one right at the exit. Order doesn't matter, but I recommend this one last for two reasons. One, because the chest spawns right near it. Two, because if you clear out all the enemies in the process, you can then just pick up the chest and exit to the next room.

[image: Exit Rock location]

Once you've clanged all those rocks, pick up your prize!

> It's a **Common Shield**! This one gives +25 Defense.